# Use external data in Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb

How can I list external Json data get from mongodb into Django page?
The Json data has table structure.
Django is should just read this data not require create, update and delete actions.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any MongoDB python library (like [this](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html)). Import it in your views, get the data and send to the template as you would do with any other type of data.